# Why useSWRInfinite call my backend twice for every request?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I have a load more button, within a brand new Next.js app, that uses `useSWRInfinite`. Every time I click it it makes 2 calls to my backend. The first call is with index 0 and the second is with the incremented index.

Here is my component:

```js
function Home() {
  const { data, size, setSize } = useSWRInfinite(
    (index) => `/api/user?page=${index}&per_page=2`,
    (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json()),
    { initialSize: 1 }
  )
  return <button onClick={() => setSize(size + 1)}>{'load more'}</button>
}
```

And here is my endpoint

```js
export default (req, res) => {
  console.log('calling the backend with', req.query)
  res.send(200)
}
```

These are the logs after I've clicked the button 3 times:

```js
calling the backend with { page: '0', per_page: '2' }
calling the backend with { page: '1', per_page: '2' }
calling the backend with { page: '0', per_page: '2' }
calling the backend with { page: '2', per_page: '2' }
calling the backend with { page: '0', per_page: '2' }
calling the backend with { page: '3', per_page: '2' }
```

Why does it call the backend with page / index 0 and then again with the correct incremented index?

Answer (score 7):

Its a feature given in **useSWRInfinite** to validate first page before the call of every next page.
post 1.1.0 version you can disable by setting

```
revalidateFirstPage : false
```

https://github.com/vercel/swr/releases/tag/1.1.0

```
  const { data, size, setSize } = useSWRInfinite(
    (index) => `/api/user?page=${index}&per_page=2`,
    (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json()),
    { 
      initialSize: 1, 
      revalidateFirstPage : false 
    }
  )
  return <button onClick={() => setSize(size + 1)}>{'load more'}</button>
}
```

Comment: Why do we need such a behavior (revalidateFirstPage) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think in `swr.vercel.app` ([link to documentation](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/pagination)) did mentioned about the `response` being a `multiple` one as shown below.

[image]

Maybe if you could specify in your `getKey` function that you just want to make `one request` (which I think **defeat the purposes** of using the `useSWRInfinite` - for **pagination**) like shown below:-

[image]

Comment: But it is only making 2 calls. One to index 0 and one to the current index.